# How to backport the panfrost driver on the ARM Chromebook from kernel 5.15 to kernel 5.4

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, arm

I've almost completed my project : to virtualize FreeBSD on top of Linux with qemu-kvm on the ARM Chromebook.

Everything works great. Even the network on the vm. One last task needs to be accomplished.

To be able to use the panfrost graphic driver on the linux distro that I have chosen and where I have configured everything : Devuan 5.

I would like to understand what's the full procedure to upgrade the panfrost driver on the ARM Chromebook from 1.1 to 1.2.

What I did right now is to enable it for the kernel that I'm using (vers. 5.4.257).

If you want ask me because I don't use an higher kernel version,the answer is that kvm has been removed on the main line kernel of arm 32 bit starting from the version 5.7,but since kernel vers. 5.4 is still partially supported,I've decided to use it. So,using a newer kernel is not the solution here.

To enabled it,I have enabled the following parameters on the kernel config file :

```
# Graphics support

CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB_MAX_GPUS=16
CONFIG_DRM=y
CONFIG_DRM_MIPI_DSI=y
CONFIG_DRM_DP_AUX_CHARDEV=y 
CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_KMS_FB_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION=y 
CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_OVERALLOC=100 
CONFIG_DRM_LOAD_EDID_FIRMWARE=y 
CONFIG_DRM_TTM=y 
CONFIG_DRM_VRAM_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_GEM_CMA_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_GEM_SHMEM_HELPER=y 
CONFIG_DRM_SCHED=y
#I2C encoder or helper chips

CONFIG_DRM_I2C_NXP_TDA998X=y
#end of I2C encoder or helper chips

CONFIG_DRM_VGEM=m CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS=y

#CRTCs

CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_FIMD=y
CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_MIXER=y

#Encoders and Bridges

CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_DPI=y
CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_DSI=y 
CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_DP=y 
CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS_HDMI=y

#Sub-drivers

CONFIG_DRM_CIRRUS_QEMU=m 
CONFIG_DRM_RCAR_LVDS=m 
CONFIG_DRM_QXL=y 
ONFIG_DRM_BOCHS=y 
CONFIG_DRM_VIRTIO_GPU=m 
CONFIG_DRM_PANEL=y

#Display Panels

CONFIG_DRM_PANEL_LVDS=m 
CONFIG_DRM_PANEL_SIMPLE=y
#end of Display Panels

CONFIG_DRM_BRIDGE=y 
CONFIG_DRM_PANEL_BRIDGE=y

#Display Interface Bridges

CONFIG_DRM_NXP_PTN3460=y 
CONFIG_DRM_PARADE_PS8622=m 
CONFIG_DRM_ANALOGIX_DP=y
#end of Display Interface Bridges

CONFIG_DRM_PL111=m 
CONFIG_DRM_PANFROST=y 
CONFIG_DRM_PANEL_ORIENTATION_QUIRKS=y

#Frame buffer Devices
CONFIG_FB_CMDLINE=y 
CONFIG_FB_NOTIFY=y 
CONFIG_FB=y 
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID=y 
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y 
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y 
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y 
CONFIG_FB_CFB_REV_PIXELS_IN_BYTE=y 
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FILLRECT=y 
CONFIG_FB_SYS_COPYAREA=y 
CONFIG_FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT=y 
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FOPS=y 
CONFIG_FB_DEFERRED_IO=y 
CONFIG_FB_BACKLIGHT=y 
CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y 
CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING=y
#Frame buffer hardware drivers

CONFIG_FB_DA8XX=y 
CONFIG_FB_SIMPLE=y 
CONFIG_FB_SSD1307=y
#end of Frame buffer Devices

#Backlight & LCD device support
CONFIG_LCD_CLASS_DEVICE=y 
CONFIG_LCD_PLATFORM=y 
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_CLASS_DEVICE=y 
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_PWM=y 
CONFIG_VIDEOMODE_HELPERS=y 
CONFIG_HDMI=y
```

Despite some gpu regulator errors , it seems to work :

```
# dmesg | grep panfrost

[0.378992] panfrost 11800000.gpu: clock rate = 533000000
[0.379769] panfrost 11800000.gpu: failed to get regulator: -517
[0.380517] panfrost 11800000.gpu: regulator init failed -517
[1.149575] panfrost 11800000.gpu: clock rate = 533000000
[1.150987] panfrost 11800000.gpu: mali-t600 id 0x600 major 0x0 minor 0x0 status 0x1
[1.152132] panfrost 11800000.gpu: features: 00000000,10206000, issues: 00000000,31b4dfff
[1.153271] panfrost 11800000.gpu: Features: L2:0x07110206 Shader:0x00000000 Tiler:0x00000809 Mem:0x1 MMU:0x00002830 AS:0xf JS:0x7
[1.154476] panfrost 11800000.gpu: shader_present=0xf l2_present=0x1
[1.158799] [drm] Initialized panfrost 1.1.0 20180908 for 11800000.gpu on minor 0
```

What's the problem,then ? that the driver is stuck to 1.1,while it is 1.2 if kernel used is 5.15.120,as you can see below. Unfortunately I can't use kernel 5.15,but at the same time I want to have the panfrost driver version 1.2 :P

```
# dmesg | grep panfrost

[3.352617] panfrost 11800000.gpu: clock rate = 533000000
[3.354011] panfrost 11800000.gpu: mali-t600 id 0x600 major 0x0 minor 0x0 status 0x1
[3.354020] panfrost 11800000.gpu: features: 00000000,10206000, issues: 00000000,31b4dfff
[3.354027] panfrost 11800000.gpu: Features: L2:0x07110206 Shader:0x00000000 Tiler:0x00000809 Mem:0x1 MMU:0x00002830 AS:0xf JS:0x7
[3.354035] panfrost 11800000.gpu: shader_present=0xf l2_present=0x1
[3.355009] [drm] Initialized panfrost 1.2.0 20180908 for 11800000.gpu on minor 1
```

According with the tutorial below,it may be possible to upgrade it : (or at least I hope)

https://gist.github.com/tstellanova/6f7844379e358ee81b89cf6937ea8139

As you can see the proposed parameters were the following ones :

```
# meson build/ -Dgallium-drivers=lima,panfrost,kmsro,swrast
-Dplatforms=x11,drm,surfaceless -Dvulkan-drivers= -Ddri-drivers= -Dllvm=false
```

but they didn't work on my system,because the following error :

```
meson.build:21:0: ERROR: Options "drm and surfaceless" are not in allowed 
choices: "auto, x11, wayland, haiku, android, windows"
```

And if I enable "-Dvulkan-drivers=enabled" I get the following error :

```
meson.build:21:0: ERROR: Options "enabled" are not in allowed choices:
"auto, amd, broadcom, freedreno, intel, intel_hasvk, panfrost, swrast, virtio, imagination-experimental, microsoft-experimental, nouveau-experimental"
```

so I have modified them a little bit and I found the parameters below,at least didn't give any error :

```
# apt install libxcb-glx0-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-present-dev libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev 

# git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa

# cd mesa

meson setup build/ -Dgallium-drivers=lima,panfrost,kmsro,swrast -Dplatforms=x11 -Dvulkan-drivers= -Dllvm=disabled

The Meson build system Version: 1.0.1 
Source dir: /Dati/mesa 
Build dir: /Dati/mesa/build 
Build type: native build 
Project name: mesa 
Project version: 23.3.0-devel

C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 12.2.0 "cc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0")

C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.40

C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 12.2.0 "c++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0")

C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.40

Host machine cpu family: arm

Host machine cpu: armv7l

Checking if "-mtls-dialect=gnu2" runs: YES

Dependency vdpau skipped: feature gallium-vdpau disabled

Program glslangValidator found: NO

Dependency libva skipped: feature gallium-va disabled

Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)

Fetching value of define "ETIME" : 62

Checking for function "bswap32" : YES

Checking for function "bswap64" : YES

Checking for function "clz" : YES

Checking for function "clzll" : YES

Checking for function "ctz" : YES

Checking for function "expect" : YES

Checking for function "ffs" : YES

Checking for function "ffsll" : YES

Checking for function "popcount" : YES

Checking for function "popcountll" : YES

Checking for function "unreachable" : YES
Checking for function "types_compatible_p" : YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute const: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute flatten: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute malloc: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute pure: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute unused: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute warn_unused_result: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute weak: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute format: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute packed: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute returns_nonnull: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute alias: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute noreturn: YES
Compiler for C supports function attribute visibility:hidden: YES
Checking if "__uint128_t" compiles: NO
Checking for function "reallocarray" : YES
Checking for function "fmemopen" : YES
Checking if "gc-sections" : links: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=implicit-function-declaration: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=missing-prototypes: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=return-type: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=empty-body: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=int-conversion: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wimplicit-fallthrough: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmisleading-indentation: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-format-truncation: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-nonnull-compare: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-math-errno: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-trapping-math: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Qunused-arguments: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-microsoft-enum-value: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=format: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=thread-safety: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -ffunction-sections: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -fdata-sections: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=return-type: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=empty-body: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wmisleading-indentation: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-non-virtual-dtor: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-format-truncation: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-math-errno: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-trapping-math: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Qunused-arguments: NO
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -flifetime-dse=1: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-microsoft-enum-value: NO
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=format: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -ffunction-sections: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fdata-sections: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-override-init: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-initializer-overrides: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=pointer-arith: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=vla: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=gnu-empty-initializer: NO
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=pointer-arith: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=vla: YES
Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=gnu-empty-initializer: NO
Checking for function "__builtin_ia32_clflushopt" : NO
Checking if "GCC atomic builtins" compiles: YES
Checking if "GCC atomic builtins required -latomic" : links: YES
Checking if "GCC 64bit atomics" with dependency : links: YES
Library ws2_32 found: NO
Header "sys/sysmacros.h" has symbol "major" : YES
Header "sys/sysmacros.h" has symbol "minor" : YES
Header "sys/sysmacros.h" has symbol "makedev" : YES
Header "sys/mkdev.h" has symbol "major" : NO
Check usable header "sched.h" : YES
Checking for function "sched_getaffinity" : YES
Check usable header "xlocale.h" : NO
Check usable header "linux/futex.h" : YES
Check usable header "endian.h" : YES
Check usable header "dlfcn.h" : YES
Check usable header "sys/shm.h" : YES
Check usable header "cet.h" : NO
Check usable header "pthread_np.h" : NO
Check usable header "renderdoc_app.h" : NO
Check usable header "sys/inotify.h" : YES
Checking for function "strtof" : YES
Checking for function "mkostemp" : YES
Checking for function "memfd_create" : YES
Checking for function "random_r" : YES
Checking for function "flock" : YES
Checking for function "strtok_r" : YES
Checking for function "getrandom" : YES
Checking for function "qsort_s" : NO
Checking for function "posix_fallocate" : YES
Checking if "GNU qsort_r" : links: YES
Header "time.h" has symbol "struct timespec" : YES
Checking for function "thrd_create" : YES
Header "errno.h" has symbol "program_invocation_name" : YES
Header "math.h" has symbol "issignaling" : YES
Checking for function "posix_memalign" : YES
Checking whether type "struct dirent" has member "d_type" : YES
Checking if "strtod has locale support" : links: YES
Checking if "Bsymbolic" : links: YES
Checking if "version-script" : links: YES
Checking if "dynamic-list" : links: YES
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--build-id=sha1: YES
Checking for function "dlopen" : YES
Checking for function "dladdr" with dependency : YES
Checking for function "dl_iterate_phdr" : YES
Checking for function "clock_gettime" : YES
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.8.1)
Run-time dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.13
Run-time dependency libzstd found: YES 1.5.4
Run-time dependency threads found: YES
Checking for function "pthread_setaffinity_np" with dependency threads: YES
Run-time dependency expat found: YES 2.5.0
Library m found: YES
Run-time dependency libdrm found: YES 2.4.114
Run-time dependency libudev found: YES 251
Run-time dependency libelf found: YES 0.188
Run-time dependency valgrind found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Program bison found: YES (/usr/bin/bison)
Program bison found: YES 3.8.2 (/usr/bin/bison)
Program flex found: YES (/usr/bin/flex)
Run-time dependency libunwind found: YES 1.6.2
Run-time dependency x11 found: YES 1.8.4
Run-time dependency xext found: YES 1.3.4
Run-time dependency xfixes found: YES 6.0.0
Run-time dependency xcb-glx found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xcb-shm found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xcb found: YES 1.15
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.25.1)
Run-time dependency xcb-keysyms found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Run-time dependency x11-xcb found: YES 1.8.4
Run-time dependency xcb-dri2 found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xcb-dri3 found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xcb-present found: YES 1.15
Dependency xcb-shm found: YES 1.15 (cached)
Run-time dependency xcb-sync found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xshmfence found: YES 1.3
Run-time dependency glproto found: YES 1.4.17
Run-time dependency dri2proto found: YES 2.8
Run-time dependency xxf86vm found: YES 1.1.4
Run-time dependency xcb-xfixes found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xcb-randr found: YES 1.15
Run-time dependency xrandr found: YES 1.5.2

Library sensors found: NO
Program nm found: YES (/usr/bin/nm)

Program symbols-check.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3 /Dati/mesa/bin/symbols- check.py)

Program install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3 /Dati/mesa /bin/install_megadrivers.py)

Program decode.py found: YES (/Dati/mesa/src/compiler/isaspec/decode.py)

Program encode.py found: YES (/Dati/mesa/src/compiler/isaspec/encode.py)

Program ln found: YES (/bin/ln) Checking for function "mincore" : YES

Build targets in project: 214

mesa 23.3.0-devel

Directories 
prefix                       : /usr/local 
libdir                       : lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
includedir                   : include 
Common C and C++ arguments
c_cpp_args                   : -mtls-dialect=gnu2


OpenGL

OpenGL                       : YES 
ES1                          : YES 
ES2                          : YES 
Shared glapi                 : YES 
GLVND                        : NO

DRI 

Platform                     : drm 
Driver dir                   : /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri

GLX 

Enabled                      : YES 
Provider                     : dri

EGL Enabled                  : YES 
Drivers                      : builtin:egl_dri2 builtin:egl_dri3 
Platforms                    : x11 surfaceless drm xcb

GBM 

Enabled                      : YES 
Backends path                : /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gbm
Vulkan Drivers               : NO 
Video Codecs                 : NO 
APIs                         : NO
LLVM Enabled                 : NO 
Gallium Enabled              : YES 
Drivers                      : lima panfrost kmsro swrast 
Platforms                    : x11 surfaceless drm xcb 
Frontends                    : mesa 
Off-screen rendering (OSMesa): NO 
HUD lm-sensors               : NO
Perfetto Enabled             : NO

User defined options

gallium-drivers              : lima,panfrost,kmsro,swrast 
llvm                         : disabled 
platforms                    : x11 
vulkan-drivers               :

Found ninja-1.11.1 at /usr/bin/ninja
```

but the panfrost driver is still stuck at 1.1 version :

```
[drm] Initialized panfrost 1.1.0 20180908 for 11800000.gpu on minor 0
```

I tried to backport the panfrost driver to the kernel 5.4 (by copying the folder where is stored the panfrost source code on the kernel 5.15 to the folder where is the panfrost source code on the kernel 5.4 and I've launched the command :

```
make zImage modules dtbs uImage LOADADDR=0x42004000
```

Unfortunately inside the C++ code there are some errors that I don't know how to fix :

```
............
CC [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.o
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_ioctl_get_param’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:35:14: error:
‘DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_AFBC_FEATURES’ undeclared (first use in this function); did y
ou mean ‘DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_MMU_FEATURES’?
  35 |         case DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_ ## name:               \
     |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:66:17: note: in expansion of macro
‘PANFROST_FEATURE’
  66 |                 PANFROST_FEATURE(AFBC_FEATURES, afbc_features);
     |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:35:14: note: each undeclared identifier is
reported only once for each function it appears in
  35 |         case DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_ ## name:               \
     |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:66:17: note: in expansion of macro
‘PANFROST_FEATURE’
  66 |                 PANFROST_FEATURE(AFBC_FEATURES, afbc_features);
     |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_ioctl_wait_bo’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:319:15: error: implicit declaration of
function ‘dma_resv_wait_timeout’; did you mean ‘dma_resv
_wait_timeout_rcu’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 319 |         ret = dma_resv_wait_timeout(gem_obj->resv, true, true, timeout);
     |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     |               dma_resv_wait_timeout_rcu
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_ioctl_madvise’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:430:48: error: passing argument 1 of
‘drm_gem_shmem_madvise’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-
pointer-types]
 430 |         args->retained = drm_gem_shmem_madvise(&bo->base, args->madv);
     |                                                ^~~~~~~~~
     |                                                |
     |                                                struct drm_gem_shmem_object *
In file included from drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_gem.h:7,
                from drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:17:
./include/drm/drm_gem_shmem_helper.h:140:50: note: expected ‘struct drm_gem_object
*’ but argument is of type ‘struct drm_gem_shmem_obj
ect *’
 140 | int drm_gem_shmem_madvise(struct drm_gem_object *obj, int madv);
     |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_probe’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:566:30: warning: passing argument 1 of
‘drm_dev_alloc’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer
target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
 566 |         ddev = drm_dev_alloc(&panfrost_drm_driver, &pdev->dev);
     |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:11:
./include/drm/drm_drv.h:791:53: note: expected ‘struct drm_driver *’ but argument is
of type ‘const struct drm_driver *’
 791 | struct drm_device *drm_dev_alloc(struct drm_driver *driver,
     |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:262: drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.o]
Errore 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:497: drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost] Errore 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:497: drivers/gpu/drm] Errore 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:497: drivers/gpu] Errore 2
make: *** [Makefile:1750: drivers] Errore 2
```

Answer (score 0):

hm. What you see here is two things:

1. that you copied a part of what you needed to copy to your older kernel: you're trying to get symbols that do not exist yet:

```c
rivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_ioctl_get_param’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:35:14: error:
‘DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_AFBC_FEATURES’ undeclared (first use in this function); did y
ou mean ‘DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_MMU_FEATURES’?
  35 |         case DRM_PANFROST_PARAM_ ## name:               \
     |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

2. you're trying to use APIs that are different under 5.4 than 5.15:

```
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c: In function ‘panfrost_ioctl_madvise’:
drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:430:48: error: passing argument 1 of
‘drm_gem_shmem_madvise’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-
pointer-types]
 430 |         args->retained = drm_gem_shmem_madvise(&bo->base, args->madv);
     |                                                ^~~~~~~~~
     |                                                |
     |                                                struct drm_gem_shmem_object *
In file included from drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_gem.h:7,
                from drivers/gpu/drm/panfrost/panfrost_drv.c:17:
./include/drm/drm_gem_shmem_helper.h:140:50: note: expected ‘struct drm_gem_object
*’ but argument is of type ‘struct drm_gem_shmem_obj
ect *’
```

Both illustrate quite nicely why "I just copied over this subfolder" is typically not how you backport things (you don't get all you need, and there's zero guarantees that the internal APIs you're using haven't changed. So this will not work, but be very hard to debug.)

What you need to do instead is first, find the changeset that finally added the panfrost driver you want in the git history, and secondly find the common ancestor between your current kernel and that, and cherry-picki all the relevant changes in the DRM driver infrastructure from the branching point to the head of your kernel.

The honest question here is why you're using an old kernel, because frankly, whatever it is that holds you on 5.4, it's probably easier, *and* more useful, to forward-port that 5.15 than to backport one of the most modern DRM drivers back.

The good news is that maybe the situation isn't *that* dire. Hit the the #panfrost IRC channel on OFTC, and ask them. Yours *is* a live and well LTS release, so maybe someone already *has* done most of the work.

Comment: OFTC ? what's this means ?

Comment: https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/panfrost.html#chat @Marietto

Comment: I prefer this : https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/mesa-users

Comment: the MLs seems to be dead. I didn't even get any reply.

Comment: you must have send an email there less than 3 hours ago … what do you think people do all day, wait for your email?